# Applying a keras model working with greyscale images to RGB images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I followed this [basic classification TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) using the **Fashion MNIST** dataset.
The training set contains 60,000 28x28 pixels greyscale images, split into 10 classes (trouser, pullover, shoe, etc...).
The tutorial uses a simple model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

This model reaches 91% accuracy after 10 epochs.

I am now practicing with another dataset called **CIFAR-10**, which consists of 50,000 32*32 pixels RGB images, also split into 10 classes (frog, horse, boat, etc...).

Considering that both the Fashion MNIST and CIFAR-10 datasets are pretty similar in terms of number of images and image size and that they have the same number of classes, I naively tried training a similar model, simply adjusting the input shape:

```
  model = keras.Sequential([
     keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
     keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
     keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ])
```

Alas, after 10 epochs, the model reaches an accuracy of 45%. What am I doing wrong?

I am aware that I have thrice as many samples in an RGB image than in a grayscale image, so I tried increasing the number of epochs as well as the size of the intermediate dense layer, but to no avail.

---

Below is my full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pdb
import pathlib
import os
from tensorflow.keras import layers #Needed to make the model
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

IMG_HEIGHT = 32
IMG_WIDTH = 32

class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']


train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

def make_model():
      model = keras.Sequential([
         keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
         keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
         keras.layers.Dense(10)
      ])
      model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                   loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
      return model

model=make_model()
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

---

**EDIT**: In order to address colt.exe's suggestion below, I converted the CIFAR-10 images from RGB to greyscale, using:

```
rgb_weights = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]
train_images = np.dot(train_images, rgb_weights)
test_images = np.dot(test_images, rgb_weights)
```

However, using the same model with 10 epochs yields an accuracy of about 38%, even worse than before! 
I am starting to think that the Fashion MNIST is "easier" to work with since all images have a light background, whereas the CIFAR-10 consist of pictures taken outdoors in a wide variety of contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying a keras model working with greyscale images to RGB images](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/71751/applying-a-keras-model-working-with-greyscale-images-to-rgb-images)